# TNS Protocol adapter error while using sqlplus in the command prompt

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c

while I am login to sqlplus using command prompt getting protocol adapter error.

But, if I login using SQLPlus of oracle then it will login successfully.

Because of this issue, even i am not able to access TOAD.

Can anyone help me for to resolve the issue.

[**CHECK THE SCREENSHOT HERE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvMaO.png)

Copying text of LISTENER.ORA and TNSNAMES.ORA

**LISTENER.ORA**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\ProgramFiles\oracle12c\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\ProgramFiles\oracle12c\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )        
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXXXX-pc)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

**TNSNAMES.ORA**

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Your target database `ORCL` isn't defined in your tnsnames.ora, which makes me wonder whether you have more than one Oracle Client installed. The SQL*Plus in the Windows Start menu is a shortcut that specifies the full path, which might be the difference (path determines which client to use). Anyway on the command line you need to either `set local=orcl` or else `sqlplus yourusername@orcl`.

Comment: Dear William, Thank you for the help... Updated the LISTENER.ORA and also you can check the attached screenshot in above. Am using only one client.... If you check the screenshoot, it is working proper in the SQLPlus window but not working in the "Command Prompt "... Recently my operating system Windows 8 was updated automatically..

Comment: Your tnsnames.ora still doesn't define `orcl` which you use for `oracle_sid` in the screenshot. But my main suggestion was to set `local` instead of `oracle_sid`. I would leave the listener alone as it appears to be working already.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ensure your configration is true, 
Maybe, the notepad which you edit your tnsnames.ora, listener.ora files can put '....'(dots) front of each newline.

For example:

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
...(DESCRIPTION =
.....(ADDRESS_LIST =
.......(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
....)
....(CONNECT_DATA =
....(SID = CLRExtProc)
........(PRESENTATION = RO)
....)
..)
```

you can check this case with notepad++ selecting 'Show All Charecters'.